# Creating persistent volume claim with low memory like 50kb or 100kb

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have to create PVC with low memory like 20kb or 50kb because I am trying to simulate the No space found error when I am writing the file. But minimum storage is 1Mi, Is there any trick to reduce the size or fill the 80% memory of 1Mi while creating the PVC in Kubernetes?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata: 
  name: test-pvc
spec: 
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources: 
    requests: 
      storage: 20Ki
```